# Can't install mailcatcher

Tags: rubygems, mailcatcher

I installed `gem` by `sudo apt install rubygem`.

After that, I tried to install `mailcatcher` by `sudo gem install mailcatcher` but encountered some errors.

```
You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.
```

Then I installed `ruby-dev` and tried to run the command.

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed eventmachine-1.0.9.1
Successfully installed rack-1.6.13
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed thin-1.5.1
Successfully installed skinny-0.2.4
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mailcatcher:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
/usr/bin/ruby2.7 -I /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200709-11163-16xwoii.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.7
    --with-sqlcipher
    --without-sqlcipher
    --with-sqlite3-config
    --without-sqlite3-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-sqlcipher
    --without-sqlcipher
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/gem_make.out
```

Can anybody please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was missing a package.

```
sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found after lots of research that there are two flavors for ruby to install:

- **with DevKit**
- **without DevKit**

Problem is with **without DevKit**.
Install ruby (**with DevKit**) and the problem is resolved.